# Problemas con Ionic

Tags: javascript, css, nodejs, ionic, cordova

Al crear un proyecto ionic en la carpeta www no me esta creando los archivos js y de mas que normalmente haria, o desconozco si actualmente este es asi. agradezco la ayuda para salir de la duda.

La primera imagen muestra la carpeta www faltando los archivos correspondientes como por ejemplo: js

[image: La primera imagen muestra la carpeta www faltando los archivos correspondientes como por ejemplo: js]

La segunda imagen muestra como deberia ser normalmente la carpeta www

[image: La segunda imagen muestra como deberia ser normalmente la carpeta www]

Answer (score 0):

El cli de ionic lo actualizaron hace poco. Revisa la documentación (http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/). Para crear un nuevo proyecto de IONIC v1 ahora debes escribir así:

```
$ ionic start mynewapp blank --type ionic1
```

Revisa el comando start aquí: http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/start/

Espero sea ayuda.
Saludos

Comment: no ha funcionado con lo que dices